# PyQT clicked events only executes at start and never works again

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

I just started learning PyQT and using it with PySide2. I got the idea of how button events work with binding clicked events, however, I have a problem.

My click events execute randomly on startup -don't understand either- and after the execution clicking these QButtons does not invoke binded methods.

```
class StartWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button_orginial = QPushButton('Show Original')
        self.button_orginial.setStyleSheet("background-color: #4592af; color: black;")
        self.button_prediction = QPushButton('Show Prediction')
        self.button_prediction.setStyleSheet("background-color: #e3c4a8; color: black;")

        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_orginial)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.button_prediction)

        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.button_prediction.clicked.connect(self.ShowPrediction())
        self.button_orginial.clicked.connect(self.ShowOriginal())

        self.InitWindow()
   

    def InitWindow(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("xxx")    
        self.setGeometry(500,500,940,360)
        self.setLayout(self.verticalLayout)

    def ShowPrediction(self):
        self.predictImg = QLabel(self)
        self.predictImg.setPixmap(self.genImage("prediction"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.predictImg)
        print("pred clicked")
    
    def ShowOriginal(self):
        self.showImage = QLabel(self)
        self.showImage.setPixmap(self.genImage("original"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.showImage)
        print("org clicked")
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = StartWindow()
    window.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
    #window.showFullScreen()
    window.show()
    app.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
self.button_prediction.clicked.connect(self.ShowPrediction())
self.button_orginial.clicked.connect(self.ShowOriginal())
```

To this:

```
self.button_prediction.clicked.connect(self.ShowPrediction)
self.button_orginial.clicked.connect(self.ShowOriginal)
```

What you're doing is trying to bind the value returned by your callbacks to the `clicked` signal, which is wrong. This is also why the callbacks are triggered once the program starts, since you're asking them to be evaluated before passing them to `connect`.

You want to bind the function object to the `clicked` signal.

Comment: Oh, silly me. Now I got it, I was invoking the functions because instead of giving them as a parameter, I was calling them. Thank you!